# Syncing a folder between Laptop and Linux server

Tags: sync

I usually use Dropbox or Ubuntu One to sync my different devices. Now I need to sync contents of a folder with a folder on a Linux server. Note that I may make change files on both sides. The first one is my laptop and the second is a computing server that I have ssh access to (regular user but not root access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with **rsync**. I'm very happy about my decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Dropbox for linux](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)

You will be able to specify the folder you want to sync the account ect.

i found a nice tutorial showing this  :
[link](http://ubuntuservergui.com/ubuntu-server-guide/install-dropbox-ubuntu-server)